# Settimeout() doesn't wait. Why?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, settimeout

In upper part, both `settimeout`s inside "if" work properly. However `settimeout`s in lower part, the ones inside "else" does not wait. As far as I can see, I've written them in exact same style in both parts. What could be the reason ?

```
    elementCopy.addEventListener('mouseleave',()=>{
                    elementCopy.classList.add('leavin');
                    setTimeout(() => {                                         //  THESE WORK PROPERLY
                        elementCopy.style.width = '36vw';
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            elementCopy.parentElement.removeChild(elementCopy);
                        }, 400);         
                    }, 400);
                })
            }
            else{
                element.classList.add('card-active');
                element.addEventListener('mouseleave',()=>{
                    element.classList.add('leavin-mob');
                    
                    setTimeout(() => {                                         //  THESE DOESN'T
                        element.style.height = '38vh';
                        setTimeout(() => {
                        }, 400);
                    }, 400);
                })
            }
```

Comment: "Wait" for what exactly? `setTimeout` doesn't wait. It schedules the function to be called in the future.

Comment: What does the  `else{` does here?

Comment: @Bamak The upper code is last part of the if statement, I didn't copy it as a whole because it's not needed. Else is when the condition in "if" is not met.

Comment: @FelixKling yeah, but it doesn't schedule it. I don't know why. It executes the code as soon as event is triggered, while it should wait for 400 milliseconds

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't wait? What happens If you make it wait 2000ms instead of 400ms?

Comment: As @Bamak said, the duration value is in ms, 400 is too lower to see a period, so you can think it's instantly

Answer (score 0):

As one of the commenters noted, `setTimeout` is not a `sleep` kind of a method.

```
 setTimeout(() => {                                        
      element.style.height = '38vh';             
  }, 800);
```

Simply increase the timeout value if you need it later.

To explain this further, a nested `setTimeout` is rare unless you are doing something in the second timeout, the code itself as you have written works fine but it has nothing to execute - it's also set to 400ms which is a super small time. You can run the code below to see the second timeout works after 4 seconds.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  //  THESE DOESN'T
  console.log("This is 400ms!");
  //element.style.height = '38vh';
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(
      "This is 4 seconds but you usually would call something else here otherwise it has no effect or value"
    );
  }, 4000);
}, 400);
```